# Python Selenium cant recognize the search result from google

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, web-scraping

hey i looked and tested over 2 to 3 hours couldnt find anything which seems to help me.
i want that python types to google search bar something and copy the result.

```
<div id="resultStats">Ungefähr 4.440.000 Ergebnisse<nobr> 
#that resultstats the text i want to copy the text which is inside ><
```

Code:

```
test = webdriver.Chrome('.\chromedriver.exe')
test.get('https://www.google.de')
test.find_element_by_id('lst-ib').send_keys('test123123')
webdriver.ActionChains(test).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
test.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultStats"]/text()').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v')

print(test)
```

The Error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12366/devtools/browser/cc7779e1-c661-4adc-91e4-067b256718db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:./niche.py", line 34, in <module>
    test.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultStats"]/text()').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v')
  File "C:.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 385, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[@id="resultStats"]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an
element.
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `copy the result` ?

Comment: i want to paste it in google spreadsheet, but thats not the main problem i will figure it how to do it later on^^

Comment: like if you type '123123' in google, then lets say the search result is 
approximately 100 results 
I want to copy the 'approximately 100 results' or better just the '100'

Comment: Each of the 100 result consists of a set of different elements e.g. div, img, anchor, text, etc. What exactly do you want to copy and where do you want to copy?

Comment: <div class="appbar" id="appbar"><style>#resultStats{position:absolute;top:0;-webkit-transition:all 220ms ease-in-out}.hdtb-ab-o #resultStats{opacity:0;top:13px;}</style><div id="extabar"><div id="topabar" style="position:relative"><div class="ab_tnav_wrp" id="slim_appbar"><div id="resultStats">>>>>Ungefähr 4.440.000 Ergebnisse<<<<<<nobr> (0,40 Sekunden)&nbsp;</nobr></div><div id="sbfrm_l"></div></div></div><div style="display:none" id="botabar"></div></div><div></div></div>
that >>>><<<<< i want to copy

Comment: <div id="resultStats">Ungefähr 4.440.000 Ergebnisse<nobr>
that resultstats the text i want to copy the text which is inside ><

Comment: Can you update the question with this information?

Comment: @DebanjanB okey done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the id to locate the element:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('resultStats')
```

Here is a complete working example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# create your webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# open google
driver.get('http://www.google.com')

# locate the search field
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')

# type "foo" into search field
search_box.send_keys('foo')

# execute a search
search_box.submit()

# locate the resultStats element
result_stats = driver.find_element_by_id('resultStats')

# print the text of resultStats
print(result_stats.text)
```

this will print:

`About 27,000,000 results (0.39 seconds)`

Comment: Sir can you help me to identify the language containing `Ungefähr` and `Ergebnisse` :)

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Thanks alot ^^
->DebanjanB Yes it is german 
ungefähr = approximitaly, estimate or about - It means a number which is not the exact number,
Ergebnisse = results

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Thanks. KaanDev I just didn't understand what the wordings were. Count yourself as the luckiest one to be answered by Corey :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find your string and print it as follows:

```
yourText = test.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultStats"]').text

print(yourText)
```